# Integrating a ratio with square root

Tags: calculus

What's the best way to evaluate an antiderivative like this one $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x-2}}{x+1}dx\ ?$$

I tried a $u$ substitution with $x-2$ and $x+1$ and neither got me a nicer looking integrand.  There are no squared terms so a trig sub doesn't leap out to me.  What's the way to do this?

Comment: don't sweat too much: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28%E2%88%9A%28x-2%29%29%2F%28x%2B1%29

Comment: How about $x-2 = u^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct to substitute $u = x-2$ is good. The radicand must be positive, so a more convenient substitution here is $u^2 = x-2$. This gives $2u\ \mathrm du = \mathrm dx$, so we have:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x-2}}{x+1}\ \mathrm dx = \int \frac{u}{u^2+3}2u\ \mathrm du.$$

You can take it from here.

Comment: Also note that you can get to the same result after starting with $u=x-2$ by proceeding with a second substitution, $v^2=u$.